# Is there a way to run "sys.list_modules" command without a minion?

Tags: salt-stack

As far as the documentation goes, if one would like to query for available execution modules, the following command should be used:

```
salt '<minion_name>' sys.list_modules
```

My question is, 
 - whether it possible to run the above without a minion? 
  
(e.g `salt sys.list_modules` , isn't it cleaner?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just want to know all the modules available to you, or the latest modules available for the current saltstack version.

```
salt-call --local sys.list_modules
```

Comment: If by "without a minion" you mean not needing to target a minion but run the command locally, then mootmoot's example is correct.

Comment: Yes, that exactly what mean. Thank you